# Squish 3 rows with same ID and null cells into one row with no null cells

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with data consistently in the format:

```
ID C2 C3 C4
-- -- -- --
 1 A
 1    B
 1       C
 2 A
 2    B
 2       C
```

I would like the output to be

```
ID C2 C3 C4
-- -- -- --
 1 A  B  C
 2 A  B  C
```

But over a larger dataset where each id has 3 rows in the style shown above where the table has cells with data in a diagonal format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `MAX()` (for example) to pick the non-null values:

```
select id, max(c2), max(c3), max(c4)
from tablename
group by id
```

Comment: Oh of course, now i feel stupid! Brainfart. Thanks a lot.